# Resize the webpage for responsive web layout

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I have developed the site in bootstrap. when i'm trying to resize site in browser the text are not re-sizing properly. I have tried few things in bootstrap, nothing is working great in text level.

here my attempt to testing the site http://i.giphy.com/xT0BKp4niP44vGOjmM.gif

Please have a look and let me know if any suggestions to make the site looks great when we resize the browser windows as well as for tablet + mobile too.

Comment: Please share code not pictures/videos, we can't know what's happening by looking at screencasts

Answer (score 1):

You can use media querys for examle:

```
p {
    font-size:80px;
}

@media (max-width:800px) {
    /* here goes your text code , you need to change text size here for example */
    p {
        font-size:30px;
    }
}
```

- [**LOOK HERE**](https://jsfiddle.net/qbbrv5h0/) for a Fiddle.
- [**LOOK HERE**](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/) for a Fiddle for ALL SIZE OF SCEENS

See also [**this Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/dxst0be3/).

```
p {
    font-size:30px;
    font-size:10vw;
}
```